# What happen if I did not use GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call

Tags: paypal

I am first time working with paypal.
After going through all the documentation I have found the following way(API Calls) to create a recurring subscription.

SetExpressCheckout->GetExpressCheckoutDetails->DoExpressCheckoutPayment->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

I have worked in sandbox environment and I did the following thing.

SetExpressCheckout-> Redirected to Url with token

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=xxxx

logged in using my sandbox paypal account.

click on agree and continue.

Took token from the above and Passed to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API.

**The above process which I followed is working correctly and I am able to see the deduction of amount in one account and addition of amount in another account (amount is specified in API call)**.

So what If I did not called GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

**Specially DoExpressCheckoutPayment(What if did not used).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be just fine, as you've seen by testing.

DoExpressCheckoutPayment is not required if you're using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile to setup a profile.  The CRPP call does not require the PayerID, which is what you would typically need to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails for, so if you don't need any other information from GECD then what you're doing will be just fine.

I typically like to call GECD anyway because then I can save more details about the customer and the order.